# ANDROID Volley + Gson (POST)

Tags: android, android-volley, gson

hello.

I want to make a post request using gson.

I got the class implemented into android website...
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/request-custom.html

```
UserRequestHelper.userRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndpointURL.USUARIO, null, new Response.Listener<Usuario>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Usuario response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro ao realizar cadastro.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

I need a body to send the user? How i send the object user to make a post request?

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

you have to override getBody :

```
    @Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return gson.toJson(dataIn).getBytes();
}
```

the whole example class(form the same link) edited:

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Response.Listener<T> listener;
private final Object dataIn;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 * @param headers Map of request headers
 */
public GsonRequest(String url, Object dataIn, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                   Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    this.dataIn = dataIn;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return gson.toJson(dataIn).getBytes();
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Than i just need to build an object like User user = new User(); user.setName("test"); and pass the user into the dataIn variable?

Comment: yes. you may want to change the type from Object to User if you are going to pass that type only

Comment: Than i can  change the object to User type... But what clazz is for than? Could you explain me?

Comment: it is for the type you are going to receive. check the tutorial in your link for more info

Comment: I'm getting this when i'm trying to make a GET request...  I need to create a new constructor for GET and keep this onoe for POST and PUT? java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108408/discussion-between-djodjo-and-felipe-a).

Comment: and don't forget to override `getBodyContentType`