# Display JSON data on Android using GSON and Volley

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, gson

Hello I'm new to android programming and trying to learn it. I followed [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley) tutorial and it's working fine however I don't know how to display the records in the listview.

The PostActivity.java file is from the tutorial is below,

```
package com.kylewbanks.gsonvolleytutorial;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import static android.R.id.list;

    public class PostActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts.json";

        private RequestQueue requestQueue;
        private Gson gson;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
            gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            fetchPosts();
        }

        private void fetchPosts() {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

        private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), response);

                List<Post> posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Post[].class));
                //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), posts.size() + " posts loaded.");

                List listview = (List) findViewById(R.id.postListView);

                for (Post post : posts) {
                    //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), post.ID + ": " + post.title);
                }
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.single_post_item, posts);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        };

        private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), error.toString());
            }
        };
    }
```

Post.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Post {

    @SerializedName("id")
    long ID;

    @SerializedName("date")
    Date dateCreated;

    String title;
    String author;
    String url;
    String body;

}
```

activity_post.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PostActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/postListView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

single_post_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update Error 1 :

```
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of entity","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_post.xml","position":{"startLine":0}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of entity","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\single_post_item.xml","position":{"startLine":0}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_post.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\single_post_item.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Update Error 2 :

```
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\src\main\java\com\kylewbanks\gsonvolleytutorial\PostActivity.java:70: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous Listener<String>>,int,int,List<String>)
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_post_item,R.id.textView, posts_strs);
                                               ^
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener<String>> cannot be converted to Context)
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener<String>> cannot be converted to Context)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: why  Post[].class and not  Post.class?

Comment: Can you add source code of `single_post_item.xml` ?

Comment: I added all the files @GaëtanMaisse

Comment: I am very new to the android programming so this is what I get for the tutorial [link](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley) @Nirel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is only one `TextView` in your list layout mean you intended to display single item

1.) Create a `String` arraylist and add elements to it

2.) Mention `@+id/textView"` as 3rd parameter while creating adapter

[`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E))

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts.json";

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Gson gson;
    private List<String> posts_strs ;

    // keep it here for later use in other methods
    private List<Post> posts ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // code

        // initialize list
        posts_strs = new ArrayList<String>();

        // code
    }


    private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), response);

            posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Post[].class));
            //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), posts.size() + " posts loaded.");

            List listview = (List) findViewById(R.id.postListView);

            for (Post post : posts) {
                 // add items to list
                 posts_strs.add( post.ID + ": " + post.title);
                //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), post.ID + ": " + post.title);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PostActivity.this,R.layout.single_post_item
                     ,R.id.textView, posts_strs);
            //   use the textview id posts_strs while creating adapter
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    };
        // code

}
```

Issues :

1.) Add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top in your both `XML` layouts `activity_post` and `single_post_item`

2.) Use `PostActivity.this` instead of `this` because `this` will refer to anonymous `Response.Listener<String>` class instead of `PostActivity`.

Comment: try the updated code and mention the error details if there will be any

Comment: you have to use `posts_strs` in adapter i updated this in my code way back in time , simply try the current code , surely work

Comment: I tried the updated code and here is the errors: `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_post.xml` and `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\src\main\res\layout\single_post_item.xml` @Pavneet Singh

Comment: post complete errors in your post at the end , these lines are just paths there is useful error details

Comment: I have posted the complete errors also I have updated the PostActivity.java file with your updated code which I put into my post as well  @Pavneet Singh

Comment: you need to add this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top in your both `XML` layouts `activity_post` and `single_post_item`

Comment: I added the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` to the files now I have another error, which is ArrayAdapter error, I have updated the error in the post to see the details. @Pavneet Singh

Comment: use `PostActivity.this` instead of `this` OMG , you said your current code was working fine

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, really really appreciated. @Pavneet Singh

Comment: Can I use POST method and send some parameters to the SERVER so I can get the needed json array instead of the whole information? @Pavneet Singh

Comment: yes you can but that depends if the link (https://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts.json) supports the Post request with your requirements although it's just a json file given to you for demo and is there is still any issue with current code ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the current code, it is working perfectly, all I need to do some how to use the POST method and send operation and id parameters to the server which accepts post requests. For example, I need to send operation=show,id=1 to get the list with the id 1 @Pavneet Singh

Comment: since you can't control the server link and this seems like just a demo file so not possible

Comment: Your code is perfect for me and I am not going to use the demo link, I have a different php rest api which I will use for the post arrays. I find the post method for gson frrm this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432152/android-volley-gson-post) How can I implement this into your code? @ Pavneet Singh

Comment: now that i totally a different question and your posted issue has been resolved , read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481228/post-method-using-volley-not-working) and you can post another question after if you need

Comment: Sorry to bother you but you again but I am having an error `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path` I have updated the java file in the post and the full error description in error update 3 @Pavneet Singh

Comment: You should not change your original question which has been solved , if you have new issue then you can post new question instead of turning old one into completely a new question  , that's how  Stackoverflow works so you must rollback to previous edit and post new question Although the current issue is about  your `GSON` code so you can do some research about this error `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT` something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\GSONVolleyTutorial-master\app\src\main\java\com\kylewbanks\gsonvolleytutorial\PostActivity.java:70: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous Listener<String>>,int,int,List<String>)
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_post_item,R.id.textView, posts_strs);
                                               ^
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener<String>> cannot be converted to Context)
    constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous Listener<String>> cannot be converted to Context)
```

Since the code which creates the `ArrayAdapter` is inside an anonymous inner class, `this` refers to the instance of that anonymous class. To access the `this` pointer of the `PostActivity` instance which contains the anonymous class, use `PostActivity.this` instead.